# Free printable background map: land use, rivers, etc

Tags: qgis, printing, data

I am looking for a free printable background map of europe which should look more or less like the OCM landscape: 
land use, major rivers, coast lines
Is there any WMS or raster set whiche enables me to make quick distributions maps of species in Qgis and print it.

Borders would be useful but not essential, labels of cities, major roads etc. are not need nor wished.

Comment: you can use the openlayers plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) offers raster and vector data with scale-depended detailing.

Another solution for background maps is the stamen watercolor TMS based on OpenStreetMap data:

http://maps.stamen.com/watercolor/#12/37.7706/-122.3782

Comment: the Natural Earth data was thing I had in mind! thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Europe you can use the [Corine Land Cover map](http://www.eea.europa.eu/publications/COR0-landcover) at 1:100k, this is land cover rather than land use but for habitat and species mapping may be more appropriate.

There are many varieties available of the dataset including;

- [2006 Seamless Vector map](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-3)
- [2006 Raster Dataset](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2006-raster-3)

Data is available for re-use under the standard [European Environment Agency licence terms](http://www.eea.europa.eu/legal/copyright), which permit **non-commercial** and **commercial re-use**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also build your own topo-maps following [this article](https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/create-great-looking-topographic-maps-in-qgis-2/). No landuse though.

Really sweet!